# How to fix "Bad notification" error happening because of "Couldn't inflate contentViews java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"?

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

Few crashes are being reported in my production android app with the following stack traces. I tried googling and search through StackOverflow but could not figure out what might be causing it. From the looks of the exception being reported, should I serialize the code posting notification from my android app?

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification(tag=null, id=100) posted from package a.b.c, crashing app(uid=10892, pid=2909): Couldn't inflate contentViewsjava.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2400)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem on some devices. Have you solved it? If so, how?

Comment: No, haven't solved it yet . Its occurrences have reduced in a later version of the app so it's on lower priority to me currently.